# regenerate prestashop category tree

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

I imported prestashop categories in 2500 from a CSV file. I respected the ties of parentage, everything works in the navigation or in the backoffice.

However, the category tree (which can be seen when we created a new product or you want to put a scene in a category) is not "update". I see all my categories ... in bulk.

How can regenerate this tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug was in prestashop. It has been fixed. They changed the categories tree in AdminScenes. The change is available on the SVN and in the future 1.4.5